# How to include the response when HTTPError is raised via raise_for_status with python-requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I have an API that returns a json message when 4xx errors occur. An example is `{'message': 'Could not decode JWT token'}`. That message is lost when I handle the exception.

```
class HttpService:
    def __init__(self, url, token):
        self.headers={"Authorization": token}
        self.requests = Requests(url)

    def get(self, path):
        try:
            response = self.requests.get(path, headers=self.headers)
            response.raise_for_status()

            return response.json()
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            raise HttpServiceException(e)

class HttpServiceException(Exception):
    pass
```

In another class I have a method like

```
def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return self.http_service.get("user/" + user_id)
        except HttpServiceException as e:
            print(e) // this prints "401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: <url>"
```

I would like to able to see the `{'message': 'Could not decode JWT token'}` as well as the `401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: <url>` message when I print the exception. 
What's the best/simplest way to achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`RequestException` has `request` and `response` attributes:

```
import requests

try:
    response = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/status/403')
    response.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(e.request)
    print(e.response)
```